# Install python 3.6.7 pip3 offline

Tags: package-management, python3, pip

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 on my computer. Sadly my pc does not have a wifi chip. I do not have ethernet in my house either. Is there a way to install pip3 or any package offline? I do not have another computer with ubuntu installed, so I cannot take the package from there.

Also there may be something wrong with my python installation (it came preinstalled with ubuntu) when I type `whereis python3` the first line says it should be in /usr/bin/python3 and /usr/lib/python3 and other directories, but I do not have it in /usr/bin, only /usr/lib.

Comment: Enter `which python`.

Comment: @Emmet ```which python``` returns nothing, but ```which python3``` returns ```/usr/bin/python3```, when I try to navigate to that location ```cd /usr/bin/python3``` it says that it's not a directory. I have also tried using ```sudo bash``` before those commands.

Comment: try `/usr/bin/python3` (without `cd` of course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to at least have an internet connection to download things, the installation can be done offline, but to have the package prepared you have to **download**—you get the idea.

Python interpreter should be included default as part of Ubuntu installation, please check this through `which python`, in my 18.04 box it returns.

```
:~$ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

Entering `/usr/bin/python3`.

```
:~$ /usr/bin/python3
Python 3.6.7 (default, Oct 22 2018, 11:32:17) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Comment: thank you, at least I know that python works. But how do I get the pip package? I have another computer (without ubuntu) which has an internet connection.

Comment: Without Ubuntu ? Then you have to download each required file in https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-pip, if you have access to Ubuntu with internet this would be alot simpler.

Comment: If you have the time, please accept this answer by clicking grey checkmark to turn into green checkmark ✅.

Comment: One more thing, now that I have the source of python-pip what do I do with it? Sorry, I'm just not very familiar with linux

Comment: Copy the source file to your Ubuntu, then open terminal - navigate to directory where the 'source' file located, do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb` then.

Comment: ```dpkg: error: archive 'python-pip_9.0.1-2.debian' is not a regular file``` why??

Comment: Download it from table that shows `architecture`, `package size` etc. this will download `.deb` file not debian

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92439/discussion-between-emmet-and-kerrot).